# Non-parametric approach to healthcare dataset?

Tags: data-mining

I have a Healthcare dataset. I have been told to look at non-parametric approach to solve certain questions related to the dataset. I am little bit confused about non-parametric approach.

Do they mean density plot based approach (such as looking at the histogram)? 
I know this is a vague question to ask here. However, I don't have access to anybody else whom I can ask and hence I am asking for some input from others in this forum.

Any response/thought would be appreciated.

Thanks and regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are not specifically referring to a plot based approach.  They are referring to a class of methods that must be employed when the data is not normal enough or not well-powered enough to use regular statistics.

Parametric and nonparametric are two broad classifications of statistical procedures with loose definitions separating them:

- Parametric tests usually assume that the data are approximately normally distributed.
- Nonparametric tests do not rely on a normally distributed data assumption.
- Using parametric statistics on non-normal data could lead to incorrect results.
- If you are not sure that your data is normal enough or that your sample size is big enough (n < 30), use nonparametric procedures rather than parametric procedures.
- Nonparametric procedures generally have less power for the same sample
  size than the corresponding parametric procedure if the data truly are normal.

Take a look at some examples of parametric and analogous nonparametric tests from [Tanya Hoskin's Demystifying Summary](http://www.mayo.edu/mayo-edu-docs/center-for-translational-science-activities-documents/berd-5-6.pdf):

[image]

Here are some summary references:

- [Another general table with some different information](http://changingminds.org/explanations/research/analysis/parametric_non-parametric.htm)
- [Nonparametric Statistics](http://www.statoek.wiso.uni-goettingen.de/veranstaltungen/graduateseminar/Nonpar2006.pdf)
- [All of Nonparametric Statistics, by Larry Wasserman](http://ksu.edu.sa/sites/py/ar/mpy/departments/math/learnResources/ResourceCenter/Documents/All%20of%20Nonparametric%20Statistics.pdf)
- [R tutorial](http://www.r-tutor.com/elementary-statistics/non-parametric-methods)
- [Nonparametric Econometrics with Python](http://statsmodels-np.blogspot.ca/)

Comment: Great answer @AN6U5. Appreciate your comments. Thanks...